# What is the formal name of diagrams like the "shader graphs" in Blender and Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, blender, diagram, class-diagram, mermaid

[Blender](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/shader_editor.html) and [Unity](https://unity.com/features/shader-graph) both offer a "Shader Editor" / "Shader Graph," a visual programming tool that shows the flow of data through individual inputs and outputs, which are color-coded by type:

[image: Example image from the Blender documentation page linked above]

Is there a consistent name for this type of visualization in the more general diagramming world? It seems similar to but more fine-grained than a [UML2 Class Diagram](https://developer.ibm.com/articles/the-class-diagram/). [This project](https://github.com/sdrdis/jquery.flowchart) calls it a "flow chart," but that seems like a potentially non-standard use of the term (e.g., [Mermaid.js' flowcharts](https://mermaid.js.org/syntax/flowchart.html) do not necessarily readily allow this level of detail). The [Rete project](https://rete.js.org/#/) seems just to call it a "visual programming" interface.

Is there a standard name for this type of visualization, not specific to visual programming?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the general name is a Node Graph.

Unity has the [GraphView](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Experimental.GraphView.GraphView.html), available in the UnityEditor.Experimental.GraphView namespace. This is the one used by Shader Graph.

Since it's 'experimental' it's not very well documented, but it's fairly easy to use.

In Unity terminology: The GraphView is the container. Nodes are the individual elements. Each node has input and/or output Ports. Ports are connected by Edges.

Comment: On Unity Website they call it Visual Scripting but it also recognised as nodes Scripting 
https://unity.com/features/unity-visual-scripting

Comment: @Cadmonkey33, thank you! That seems to be it -- searching for that led me to sites like https://www.nodegraph.com/ and https://github.com/wbkd/awesome-node-based-uis, which have been much closer and more consistent matches than I'd found before!